# Watch App don't installed on real device

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am working on a watch app. The watch Version is 3.1.3. and the iPhone version is 10.2(14c92). This app works properly on both simulator's (Mobile/ Watch).

Now I try to test the app on the real device but the problem is I am not able to install the watch app manually or automatically. I have checked the multiple links of installing the app manually or automatically and I'm sure I do same as suggested by tutorials.

The problem is when I choose my app from My watch Apps List and turn on the switch to show the app on watch, it shows the installing status for few seconds and then the switch turned off automatically. And this happens multiple time.Please suggest me what can I do to install the watch app.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YaBoiSandeep Thanks for your suggestion. I have reset all certificates but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @YaBoiSandeep can you explain what do you mean by improper naming of provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have checked multiple times my AppDelegate Class Already contains the WCSession delegate.

Answer (score 0):

After efforts of lots of hours I resolved the issue. Actually I forgot to add the UDID of watch in the provisioning profile. Just add the UDID in both provisioning profiles for watchkit extension and for watchkit app, it resolve the issue.